# ElasticLinq doesn't seem to use the correct URL

Tags: elasticlinq

I'm having a problem to get a very simple ElasticLinq search to return a result. The problem seems to be that it's sending a URL to ElasticSearch that isn't correct for the search URL. Here is what I've tried:

```
var connection = new ElasticConnection(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"), index: "mytypes");
var context = new ElasticContext(connection);
var results = (from a in context.Query<MyType>() select a).Take(10).ToArray();
```

When I execute the last line, here is the URL I see in Fiddler:

```
http://localhost:9200/mytypes/mytypes/_search
```

The problem appears to be that mytypes is used twice in the URL rather than just one time.

I've also tried not supplying a default index to the ElasticConnection constructor, in which case the search URL is the following:

```
http://localhost:9200/_all/mytypes/_search
```

In both cases I get no results back. If I submit a query using

```
http://localhost:9200/mytypes/_search
```

I get results back.

Any ideas how to get ElasticLINQ to use the correct search URL?

Answer (score 2):

The second mytypes in the URL is the strong T type from Query()

There is a default convention that a CLR type is equivalent to an Elasticsearch document type. If you don't wish to do that you can instead override ElasticMapping's GetDocumentType to return an empty or null string.

You'll want to then consider how the types do map. There are a few other options such as fully qualifying field names and inserting a field exists check on each one. (This is what we do here)

`public JohnsElasticMapping : ElasticMapping {
   public string GetDocumentType(Type type) { return null; }
}
...
var context = new ElasticContext(connection, new JohnsElasticMapping());`